# ModuleVersionNotFoundException android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

when i click on run button then i got this error

> Error:org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>
> Error:org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.

please see below screen shot

[image]

and when i try to `gradle` sync
then i got this problem

please see below screen shot

[image]

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hechat"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven" }
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:1.3.3'
    compile 'com.tubb.smrv:swipemenu-recyclerview:5.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.6.4'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:fresco-processors:2.1.0'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':cometchat_platinum-sdk')

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i have not used v-27 then why i am facing v7 issue
thanks in advance

Comment: add your cometchat app build.gradle file

Comment: please check below answer.

Comment: use `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"` . I think it is the problem.

Comment: its not working  , I have used       compileSdkVersion 25 and   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'   then why it is showing v7:27

Comment: Have you tried `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`?

Comment: yes , i tried but nothing worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add allprojects block in your app level build file

1.

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }}}
```

2.
New projects created using Android Studio 3.0 and higher also include

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}}
```

And change your compileSdkVersion to 26 and also buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" then sync your project

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i added maven {..} then after this probelm is showing  Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

Comment: change your compileSdkVersion  to 26 and also buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" then sync your project

Comment: can you tell me         Error:org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.     ,this error is showing

Comment: did you update your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
   it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have same problem i solved using  below `dependencies` of Facebook

**Use this**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

**instead of this**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are dependencies that require the entire hierarchy of modules to include the repository.

With Kotlin DSL

### build.gradle.kts (Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        
        maven(url = "<YOUR-URL>")
    }
}
```

---

With Groovy

### build.gradle (Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        
        maven {
            url '<YOUR-URL>'
        }
    }
}
```

GL

Comment: Which URL you are talking about. Please Explain this `YOUR-URL`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using old plugin so needed to add

```
jcenter()
```

After

```
mavenCentral()
```